# Unix Parameters flow

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have one function in UNIX script, where we need to pass 4 parameters. If I'm passing all parameters the UNIX script executing successfully but if I'm passing 1st parameter and 3rd parameter, UNIX script is taking the 3rd parameter as 2nd parameter and the script is failing. please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add an empty 2nd empty parameter like this:  `$ ./script.sh param1 '' param3`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what ritesh has commented: If you are passing parameters at the function call inside your script :-

```
function_name param1 '' param3 ''
```

you can still access positional parameters(function arguments) $2 and $4 inside the function but they will be NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is very useful. for Ex: If any user wants to use this function and they don't know about this, then it will be again an issue. with in the function can we write any code to understand the function that from the script we passed 2nd parameter or 4th parameter like that.

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, a simple 'if loop' inside the function that checks if a particular parameter is null or not should serve the purpose.

Comment: suppose if they gave command like function pram1 parm4, then how it works based on if loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. If you know the possible values of all parameters passed to function, then have an if loop which checks if $2 is what is intended based on its position or something else
2. If you don't know the possible values, then there is no solution(to my knowledge)

Comment: maybe, more clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve with examples will help